# Run Asp Website On IIS or Asp Developement Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a full website and everything ok in my laptop at home
and I can run it from visual studio and when I run it this notification shows on my taskbar like image below

[image]

the problem is my website is ok in my home but when I copy it on flash and put in the University PC its not running well because its run on IIS localhost and i want to run on Asp development server like in home
I tried to creat a empety website on university pc and copy my website in there but its not working
i get this error over and over when i run

> this application defines configuration in the system.web/httpmodules section

I hope you understand me!

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting in your university pc? Does it have IIS installed?

Comment: This may just be how you jave visual studio setup at school. Cant really tell with the content of yout question

Comment: yes iis installed there and i give this error this application defines configuration in the system.web/httpmodules section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development server as name suggests is only for development purpose and will only be accessed by you. If you want it to be accessible over internet then need to deploy on web server, IIS. In such case it will not use the local port anymore and rather use port 80 (http) or 443(https)